# Generate nestjs library with cli

Tags: nestjs

I would like to create a library with nestjs.

In angular i can generate a libray : ng generate library libname

Is there a command line that i can use to generate a nestjs library ?

Any help please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are working on the `nest g lib`support
checkout : [nest-cli issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/189)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run nest g library mylibrary in =^ 5.6.0 version

Answer (score 0):

you can create the library by using the following command

```
nest g lib libaryname
```